# Internal error - Fitting AutoML model NL in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl, gcp-ai-platform-training, google-cloud-automl-nl

Good day!
I'd got an internal error during learning for AutoML in NL in GCP one-label text classification
When I'd relaunched it I'd got this error again.
I have a lot of labels, but each of then has more than 10 samples.
What's the problem is? How can i describe it?
[image]

I also had a problem during loading data, but models had fitted ok, and i had no problems with it. But may be it's not good and can be connected with my problem
[image]

Comment: Are the files mentioned in the error message existing in your project? If not, were you given access to the bucket/files?

Comment: yes, it's existing, and I've given all possible access for read and write to these files

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this problem with using old natural language engine in GCP. The new functionalituy (AI Platform (Unified) is still under developing and may cause such errors. The same dataset was succsesfully path on natural language AutoML.